# How to return only the updated subdocument inside of array after an update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a user model with the following schema

```
{
  _id: userId,
  inbox: {
    inbox: [Array of message documents],
    sent: [Array of message documents],
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get only the updated subdocument after an update in mongodb / mongoose ?

The update is good i just want to return the updated subdocument instead of querying the db again

```
db.getCollection("users").findOneAndUpdate(
  { "inbox.sent._id": ObjectId("5cea23be8c03c800d43a8376") },
  { "$set": { "inbox.sent.$.inTrash": false } },
  { "inbox.sent.$": 1 } <-- how to return only the subdocument like in a query
);
```

expected output the array at inbox.sent with only the updated doc

```
{
  _id: userId,
  inbox: {
    sent: [{ updated doc}]
  }  
}
```

Comment: How does your schema look like? And what expected output you want after update?

Comment: @Fanpark I know you can select fields but because it is an array i will get the full length array and i will need to iterate over it to find the sub document. is there a way to get an array with a single element like if we do `db.getCollection("users").findOne(
  { "inbox.sent._id": ObjectId("5cea23be8c03c800d43a8376") },
  { "inbox.sent.$": 1 }
)`

Comment: Please check both duplicate answer. One will explain your how can you project in findOneAndUpdate and another will show you how positional operator can help to project array elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a callback to the `findOneAndUpdate` function

e.g:

```
db.getCollection("users").findOneAndUpdate(
  { "inbox.sent._id": ObjectId("5cea23be8c03c800d43a8376") },
  { "$set": { "inbox.sent.$.inTrash": false } },
  { "inbox.sent.$": 1 },
  function (err, res) {
    //here you have the res, which will be the affected record
  }
);
```

Comment: I know that you need to provide a `cb`, the update returns the entire document with the entire `inbox.sent` array

Comment: Unfortunately the is no other way with the `findOneAndUpdate` function to target specific areas of the the record. Do you want just the updated part of the array?